# Implementing Custom Modules in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I am new to Drupal and I have to write a new custom payment method for ubercart. I briefly understand the hooks system that Drupal has.

In the ubercart api documentation, http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_payment_method:

```
<?php
function uc_payment_payment_method() {
  $methods[] = array(
    'id' => 'check',
    'name' => t('Check'),
    'title' => t('Check or Money Order'),
    'desc' => t('Pay by mailing a check or money order.'),
    'callback' => 'uc_payment_method_check',
    'weight' => 1,
    'checkout' => TRUE,
  );
  return $methods;
}
?>
```

However, when i look at how the paypal module is implemented:

```
$methods[] = array(
    'id' => 'paypal_wps',
    'name' => t('PayPal Website Payments Standard'),
    'title' => $title1 . $title2,
    'review' => t('PayPal'),
    'desc' => t('Redirect users to submit payments through PayPal.'),
    'callback' => 'uc_payment_method_paypal_wps',
    'redirect' => 'uc_paypal_wps_form',
    'weight' => 1,
    'checkout' => FALSE,
    'no_gateway' => TRUE,
  );
```

There are some special fields such as redirect and no_gateway. Where do I find the documentation for these to see what do these fields actually do?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Don't forget that the only customization you can do is payment methods.. 
May be Paypal module introduces a new key to this array ? This is not a rare case. 
Sorry i couldn't find a link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check Ubercart API docs at http://api.ubercart.me/.

But I see that for [`hook_uc_payment_method()`](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!payment!uc_payment!uc_payment.api.php/function/hook_uc_payment_method/7), there isn't any more information here than at the documentation that you referred to.

Looking at the PayPal payment module as an example, I've been able to figure out that the redirect callback specifies the code behind the final checkout button that redirects to the off-site payment gateway.

So the `uc_paypal_wps_form` is the form generated behind the final checkout button. If you inspect the rendered checkout button element with Firebug, you'll see the form generated by this function.

I also have an example posted on my blog at http://nmc-codes.blogspot.ca/2012/07/how-to-create-custom-ubercart-payment.html

As for the `no_gateway` option, this is the only piece of code I can find in the ubercart module that refers to it:

```
if (empty($method['no_gateway'])) {
  $gateways = _uc_payment_gateway_list($id, TRUE);
  $options = array();
  foreach ($gateways as $gateway_id => $gateway) {
    $options[$gateway_id] = $gateway['title'];
  }
  if ($options) {
    $form['pmtable'][$id]['uc_payment_method_' . $id . '_checkout']['#title'] .= ' (' . t('includes %gateways', array('%gateways' => implode(', ', $options))) . ')';
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem to do much but add to the label/title of payment method when you view it in the admin list of payment methods at `admin/store/settings/payment`

Comment: I follow your blog at http://nmc-codes.blogspot.ca/2012/07/how-to-create-custom-ubercart-payment.html
However, I unable to unable the payment method modules. Can help me?

Comment: @peifa I suggest you come up with a specific question about where or how you are stuck and ask it on this forum.